# What does the npm -S flag mean?

Tags: npm

What does the `-S` flag for npm mean? I see it referenced [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/typescript) but https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install does not cover what the `-S` is.

```
npm i -S @types/google-apps-script
```

Comment: Just for completion, if somebody arrived here through searching for `-s` flag (lowercase s) by flawed search engine results, lowercase s is shortcur for `--silent`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The 'S' option is the Save option in npm. It adds the npm package to your dependencies for your project. It's the same as `--save`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you! I wish the documentation clearly stated that shorthand somewhere.

Comment: "It's the same as --save-dev." -- this is wrong. The shorthand of --save-dev is -D.
Also, --save, or -S, is no longer necessary as this is done by default since npm 5. https://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500

Comment: what's the reason for using synonym for --save vs -s ? Unnecessary creates confusion

Comment: so you don't have to type as much

Answer (score 61):

`-S` is shorthand for `--save`, and it adds the package you're installing to the dependencies in your `package.json` file (which can be created with `npm init`). However, `--save` or `-S` is totally unnecessary if you're using npm 5 or above since it's done by default.