# What does the command `npm i -S packagename` do and what is the yarn equivalent to this npm command?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

What does `-S` stand for in an npm command? And where the added package is added in package.json? in "devDependencies" or in "dependencies" collection?

I have seen other questions like the ones below, but none of them covers the yarn equivalence for that:

[What is the equivalent of "npm install <package_name> --save" in Yarn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134390/what-is-the-equivalent-of-npm-install-package-name-save-in-yarn)

[What does the npm -S flag mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793045/what-does-the-npm-s-flag-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `npm install --help` (or https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config): `-S` means `--save` which has been `true` by default since like forever, and is [documented](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#save) as:

> Save installed packages to a package.json file as dependencies.

Contrary to `--save-dev`:

> Default: false
>
> Save installed packages to a package.json file as devDependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what is then the yarn command for the same npm command? I know that npm i is equal to yarn add, but what about npm i -S?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134390/what-is-the-equivalent-of-npm-install-package-name-save-in-yarn

Comment: I have seen that list, but there is no entry for npm i -S, instead there is something for npm install --save-dev, which is not exactly npm i -S.

Comment: As you can read in my answer, `-S` means `--save`, which is true by default, so omitting it achieves exactly the same as specifying it.

Comment: So you mean the command 'yarn add' is the same as 'npm i -S' or 'npm i', right?

Comment: I conclude your answer plus the discussion under it as the answer to my question: "npm i -S pkgname"  === "yarn add pkgname", and the added package is added to the dependencies in package.json file.